# Access Image Data Buffer in CameraX

Tags: android, image, pixel, android-camerax

I use the new CameraX API for taking a picture like this :

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener{
            val file = File(externalMediaDirs.first(),
                "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg")

            imageCapture.takePicture(executor, object :
                ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedListener() {
                override fun onCaptureSuccess(
                    image: ImageProxy,
                    rotationDegrees: Int)
                {

                    // DO I NEED TO USE 'image' TO ACCESS THE IMAGE DATA FOR MANIPULATION (e.g. image.planes)

                }

                override fun onError(
                    imageCaptureError: ImageCapture.ImageCaptureError,
                    message: String,
                    cause: Throwable?
                ) {
                    val msg = "Photo capture failed: $message"
                    Log.e("CameraXApp", msg, cause)

                }
            })

            imageCapture.takePicture(file, executor,
                object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener {

                    override fun onError(
                        imageCaptureError: ImageCapture.ImageCaptureError,
                        message: String,
                        exc: Throwable?
                    ) {
                        val msg = "Photo capture failed: $message"
                        Log.e("CameraXApp", msg, exc)

                    }

                    override fun onImageSaved(file: File) {
                        val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: ${file.absolutePath}"
                        Log.d("CameraXApp", msg)



                    }
                }
        }
```

I want to apply some image processing with Renderscript when the image is captured. But I dont know how to access the pixels of the image that is captured. 
Can someone provide a solution ? 
I tried it with `image.planes` within the onCaptureSuccess() callback (see comment)

I must admit that I am new to this and do not know really what planes are. Before this, I only worked with Bitmaps ( doing some image processing on Bitmaps with Renderscript). Is there a way to turn a frame/image into a Bitmap and apply some sort image processing on it "on the fly" before saving it as a file ? If yes, how ? The official CameraX guidelines are not very helpful when it comes to this.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably very late answer but the answer is in `ImageCapture` callback.

You get an Image with

```
val image = imageProxy.image
```

Notice this will only work when you have images in YUV format, in order to configure your camera with that you can do it with

```
imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
                .setBufferFormat(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)
                 ...
                .build()
```

Now can get `image.planes`

The default image format is `JPEG`
and you can access the buffer with

```
buffer: ByteBuffer = imageProxy.image.planes[0].getBuffer()
```

and if you plan on setting it to YUV

```
val image = imageProxy.image
val yBuffer = image.planes[0].buffer // Y
val uBuffer = image.planes[1].buffer // U
val vBuffer = image.planes[2].buffer // V
```